# I've 2very similar screens,where only 2widgets change from one to the other.There's any way to avoid having to repeat the logic and UI on each screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

the screen boils down to a text field, 2 choice buttons and the widget that varies, being on one of the screens another text field or 4 choice buttons ([FilterChip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilterChip-class.html)).
I would like to save lines of code as the logic and UI are pretty much the same.

I thought about using an abstract class, but I don't know how it works right